# Golang: Convert float to hex string

Tags: go

How to convert a **float64** value to **hex string** in golang?(IEEE 754 format)

Sample:
-561.2863 to 0xc40c5253

Comment: Waht do you try so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`math.Float(64|32)bits`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float64bits):

```
fmt.Printf("%x\n", math.Float32bits(-561.2863))
fmt.Printf("%x\n", math.Float64bits(-561.2863))
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/WEZEtCU1Zl.